# using docker-compose without sudo doesn't work

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, root

I was recently told that running `docker` or `docker-compose` with sudo is a big nono, and that I had to create/add my user to the `docker` group in order to run `docker` and  `docker-compose` commands without `sudo`. Which I did, as per the [documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)

Now, `docker` runs normally via my user. e.g. :

```
~$ docker run hello-world

Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
b8dfde127a29: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:df5f5184104426b65967e016ff2ac0bfcd44ad7899ca3bbcf8e44e4461491a9e
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (amd64)
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
 https://hub.docker.com/

For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/get-started/
```

But when I try to run docker-compose, I get a `Permission Denied`

```
~$ docker-compose --help

-bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose: Permission denied
```

Could you please explain how this works ? I thought having a `docker` group enabled the usage of these commands because the binaries belong to this group, but actually they don't, they only belong to `root`...

```
~$ ls -al /usr/bin/docker*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  71706288 Jul 23 19:36 /usr/bin/docker
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    804408 Jul 23 19:36 /usr/bin/docker-init
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2944247 Jul 23 19:36 /usr/bin/docker-proxy
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 116375640 Jul 23 19:36 /usr/bin/dockerd
```

```
~$ ls -al /usr/local/bin/
total 12448
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 May 26 11:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root     4096 May 14 19:36 ..
-rwxr--r--  1 root root 12737304 May 26 11:08 docker-compose
```

So, how does this work?
And how do I enable `docker-compose` to run for users that belong to the `docker` group?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```bash
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

---

As of Jun 2023, the `docker-compose` command has been deprecated in favor of the compose plugin.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/linux/

> Install the Compose plugin

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-compose-plugin

...

docker compose ps # note that docker and compose are now two words.
```

---

Will turn your permissions on.

`docker-compose` is just a wrapper, and it uses an external *docker daemon*, the same way the `docker` command doesn't actually run anything but gives an order to a *docker daemon*.

You can change the docker daemon you communicate with using the `DOCKER_HOST` variable. By default, it is empty ; and when it is empty, both `docker` and `docker-compose` assume it is located at `/var/run/docker.sock`

According to the [dockerd documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option) :

> By default, a unix domain socket (or IPC socket) is created at /var/run/docker.sock, requiring either root permission, or docker group membership.

And this is enforced by giving read and write access to the docker group to the socket.

```bash
$ ls -l /var/run/docker.sock 
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 nov.  15 19:54 /var/run/docker.sock
```

As described in https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/, to add an user to the `docker` group, you can do it like that :

```bash
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER # this adds the permissions
newgrp docker # this refreshes the permissions in the current session
```

---

That being said, using `docker` with `sudo` is *the same as* using it with the `docker` group, because giving acces to the `/var/run/docker.sock` is *equivalent* to giving full root acces:

From https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

> The docker group grants privileges equivalent to the root user. For details on how this impacts security in your system, see Docker Daemon Attack Surface.

If root permission is a security issue for your system, another page is mentioned :

> To run Docker without root privileges, see [Run the Docker daemon as a non-root user (Rootless mode)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/).

---

docker is composed of multiple elements : https://docs.docker.com/get-started/overview/

First, there are clients :

```bash
$ type docker
docker is /usr/bin/docker
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/docker
docker-ce-cli: /usr/bin/docker
```

You can see that the `docker` command is installed when you install the `docker-ce-cli` package.

Here, *ce* stands for *community edition*.

The `docker` cli communicates with the docker daemon, also known as `dockerd`.

`dockerd` is a daemon (a server) and exposes by default the unix socket `/var/run/docker.sock` ; which default permissions are `root:docker`.

There are other components involved, for instance `dockerd` uses `containerd` : https://containerd.io/

---

The rest is basic linux permission management :

- operating the docker daemon is the *same* as having root permission on that machine.
- to operate the docker daemon, you need to be able to read and write from and to the socket it listens to ; in your case it is `/var/run/docker.sock`. **whether or not you are a sudoer does not change anything to that**.
- to be able to read and write to and from `/var/run/docker.sock`, you must either be `root` or being in the `docker` group.
- `docker-compose` is another cli it has the same requirements as `docker`.

Comment: Interesting ! Actually, what I meant by "a no-no" is in the following case : `sudo docker-compose up` launches as root, so with `UID=0`, which messes up certain permissions.

Comment: Could you please provide an additional explanation or link concerning why using the command `docker`  works when a user belongs to the `docker` group? I mean the "command" that gives the order of communication to the socker still belongs to `root:root`, so how is it possible? How does it differ from using `docker-compose` ?

Comment: Also, could you please provide the location of the `docker-compose` external server/socket that contain the ownership `user:docker`; analogously with docker's `/var/run/docker.sock` ?

Comment: @Imad running `sudo docker-compose`, `docker-compose` or `docker` is the same. those programs do not do anything on their own ; they tell `dockerd` the intent of the user, and `dockerd` does it's own business. Cf the additionnal details.

Comment: @Imad both `docker-compose` and `docker` talk with `/var/run/docker.sock` by default, I added some details about that.

Comment: In very short, run `sudo chown $USER:docker /var/run/docker.sock`, it will change from "root docker" to "you docker". Then restart the service `sudo service docker restart`, and now `docker-compose up -d` will work.

Comment: @Anwar's answer worked for me on Ubuntu 22, while the suggested `chown` command in the parent didn't work. `chmod: cannot access '/usr/local/bin/docker-compose': No such file or directory`

Comment: as of now, docker-compose is deprecated over the composer plugin. you can access it with `docker compose`.  in this regard, you should use `sudo chmod a+x ...docker`, whereever your docker command is. Note that you can't have both errors: `-bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose: Permission denied` and at the same time `chmod: cannot access '/usr/local/bin/docker-compose': No such file or directory`. What exactly is your original error ?

Answer (score 9):

What worked for me was adding myself to the '**docker**' group
by running (as root, via `sudo`):

```
# usermod -a -G docker` *myUserName*
```

You may need to re-login, since current shells
may not yet "know" about being added to the **docker** group.

But you can run this following command if you don't want to re-login

```
newgrp docker
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

Comment: `newgrp docker` command easily resolved the issue for me