# How to solve docker-compose: Permission denied inside Jenkins's container

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

I'm very new to Jenkins. I'm try to execute **docker-compose** via Jenkins inside the Docker container. But what I got from the Jenkins Console Output is

> docker-compose: Permission denied

Below is my Jenkins's Docker-compose.yml,

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    privileged: true
    user: root
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 50000:50000
    container_name: jenkins-lts
    volumes:
      - ~/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - ~/.ssh:/var/jenkins_home/.ssh
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker
      - /usr/local/bin/docker-compose:/usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

And here is my Jenkinsfile,

```
pipeline {
    
    agent any

    environment {
        PATH = "$PATH:/usr/local/bin/docker-compose"
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker-compose up -d --build'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I try to find the solution via Stackoverflow and found someone suggests to do 'sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock'. But it is still not working (got the same error).

How to make the docker-compose via pipline works ?

Really thanks for every contribution.

Comment: Potentially related question here if I'm reading the problem correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68653051/21960203


As I read it, it seems the issue is just with running `docker-compose` without sudo on the machine correct?